# How to analyse data from several sheets with similar structure?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is essentially [Excel, merge two sheets with one column as key](https://superuser.com/questions/444190/excel-merge-two-sheets-with-one-column-as-key) but instead of one key column I have 3 so I cannot simply use `VLOOKUP`.

What I want is very simple: dynamically generate a master table with all the data from a set of tables combined. It should be very easy to include new rows that are added to the source tables. Eventually I will do a pivot table on the master table to get the final form as shown.

```
Source table structure:
Date | Product | Variant | Price

Desired master structure:
Source table name* | Date | Product | Variant | Price

Final form
Date | Product | Variant | Source1 | Source2 | SourceN
```

*The source table name can be added to the source table.

Comment: maybe this http://superuser.com/questions/487201/how-can-i-vlookup-in-multiple-excel-documents/487579#487579 will give you a lead/idea?

Comment: @agentmike Unfortunately I cannot use `VLOOKUP` because it only supports one key column and I have three. However, the `INDIRECT` function from that question seems to be quite useful. I guess I may have to use SQL instead of EXCEL in the end...

Comment: can you create a new column with the whole key concatenated from the 3 columns in each sheet? if yes, use INDEX+MATCH on this column